# Converting SQL hashbytes into C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm rebuilding the admin screens for our ASP.NET application and trying to replace SQL Server stored procedures with C# code.

Currently we use the following SQL to update passwords in the database:

```
update userdetail 
set passwordhash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', @Password + convert(varchar(50), salt))
```

`@Password` is declared as `varchar(30)`.

I've tried this so far:

```
private static readonly Encoding Encoding1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);

static byte[] ComputeSha512Hash(string password, string salt)
{
   using (SHA512 sha512Hash = SHA512.Create())
   {
      byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding1252.GetBytes(password);
      byte[] saltBytes = Encoding1252.GetBytes(salt);
      byte[] combinedBytes = new byte[passwordBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
      byte[] bytes = sha512Hash.ComputeHash(combinedBytes);

      return bytes;
    }
 }
```

But I'm unable to login once I've changed the password using the new admin screen, so it doesn't seem to be producing the same result was my SQL. Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: Out of interest, why limit your users to characters within the 1252 Code page for their passwords?

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't tell you. I'm working with legacy code and I wasn't resposible for the original stored procedure.

Comment: `combinedBytes` is an empty array, you're not hashing any data.

Comment: `byte[] combinedBytes = new byte[passwordBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];` should be `byte[] combinedBytes = Encoding1252.GetBytes(password + salt);` otherwise your array is empty

Comment: Like every functions or operators tha operate on strings, the results differ following wich collation is used for the string... Can you apply the same collation in your C# program as the column collation in the db... ?

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder @Charlieface. I've tried changing lines 5 and 6 for `byte[] combinedBytes = Encoding1252.GetBytes(password + salt);` but I'm still unable to login after changing the password. I've also tried `byte[] combinedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password + salt);` in case the encoding type was wrong but that didn't work either.

Comment: Can you compare the c# result with the sql result using the same password and salt? There is more to the process of creating a login and then logging in than just hashing the password so the issue could now be elsewhere.

Comment: @SQLpro sorry I'm not sure I totally understand your question so I don't know if my response is relevant, but do you mean the bit where I'm setting Encoding1252 might be wrong? passwordhash is stored as varbinary(500) in the database. Does that mean I should be encoding as some other type?

Comment: @Crowcoder if I'm comparing them correctly, they're coming back different. SQL returned '0xF1FB844...' and C# returned '0x1D338E0...'

Comment: HASHBYTES is not using the same Encoding as c#. I ran my own tests and my hashes match when I use varchar and utf8, and nvarchar and unicode.

Comment: @Hanna_Hayes in RDBMS string are not encoded the same way that C# or any other language does, because they needs to collate semantics with the parameters you want to use (CI or CS, AI or AS, WS or not, KS or KI, etc...), which are totally unknown when using an ASCII / UNICODE / UTF... encoded string. As you will see in the metadata of the database (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) the encodage, when using a semantic collation, uses an internal encodage call ISO_1... !

Comment: By the way, replacing a stored procedure in C # code is a particularly silly practice. this leads to have problems relative to the impedance mismacth, such as that of collation or NULL which is difficult to manage in addition to being counter-efficient (mure more round-trips...)!

Comment: What is the type of the column `salt`? `convert(varchar(50), salt)` suggests it may not be a string, but (for example) a `VARBINARY`, in which case you shouldn't be encoding it.